# How to get offset/sequence number from an event with spark-eventhubs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

From the code on [this page](https://github.com/hdinsight/spark-eventhubs/blob/1f8c050238bf42c705799f15a1f00291be11cb0f/examples/src/main/scala/com/microsoft/spark/streaming/examples/receiverdstream/workloads/EventhubsToAzureBlobAsJSON.scala), we can get the body part of an event out by using new String(x) since x is passed to us as a byte array. Is there anyway to get out the system properties of the event data when using this spark-eventhubs library? I would like information on either the sequence number/offset or the time the event was enqueued in this event hub.

Answer (score 0):

Use DirectStreams API which exposes `EventData` directly

```
val inputDirectStream = EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(
      ssc,
      eventHubNamespace,
      progressDir,
      Map(eventHubName -> eventhubParameters))

inputDirectStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.flatMap(eventData => new String(eventData.getBody).split(" ").map(_.replaceAll(
        "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ""))).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect().toList.
       foreach(println)
    }

// all you need here is eventData.getSystemProperties.getSequenceNumber
```